# Stanford CoreNLP example on Arabic Language

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, arabic

I am having a project on  Arabic NLP,Can I have a java example on how to use (coreNLP) Stanford  Arabic Modules (segmenter,POS tagger...)?

Comment: have to tried googling? Please read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question, in which people can help

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample command:

```
java -Xmx8g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props StanfordCoreNLP-arabic.properties -file example.txt -outputFormat text
```

Make sure you include the Arabic models jar in your CLASSPATH:

```
https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
```

That website contains a lot of documentation on Stanford CoreNLP usage.